# Excecuting shell script from chef recipe

Tags: ruby, shell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have to execute a script from recipe based on the result which I have to get from the ubuntu node. I have to get the version of agent running and based on that I have to execute script. Below is the condition in recipe which I am running.

```
notifies :run, 'bash[uninstall CloudPassage]', :immediate
only_if { Mixlib::ShellOut.new("dpkg -s cphalo | grep Version | awk '{print $2}'" -lt "3.9.5").run_command.success? }
```

but it is giving a syntax. can anyone help me with the syntax to get version number from ubuntu node.

Syntax error:

> ```
> FATAL: Cookbook file recipes/default.rb has a ruby syntax error:
> FATAL: /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks/cloudPassage/recipes/default.rb:27:syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
> FATAL: ...rsion | awk '{print $2}'" -lt "3.9.5").run_command.success? }
> FATAL: ...                               ^
> FATAL: /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/cookbooks/cloudPassage/recipes/default.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '}'
> FATAL: ... awk '{print $2}'" -lt "3.9.5").run_command.success? }
> FATAL: ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The correct-er way to write this:

```
only_if { Gem::Requirement.create('< 3.9.5').satisfied_by?(Gem::Version.create(shell_out!('dpkg -s cphalo').stdout[/^Version: (.*)$/, 1])) }
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This script checks if `cphalo` version is less than (`-lt` ) `3.9.5`.

- get the line with `cphalo` reading `Version`:

  ```
   "dpkg -s cphalo | grep Version"
  ```
- then *pipe* it to `awk`  and print second field (`$2`)

  ```
   | awk '{print $2}'"
  ```
- the result is compared to `"3.9.5"`  thanks to `-lt`

  ```
   ">result<" -lt "3.9.5"
  ```

which returns *true* or *false*.

But you must not break your string like you do with internal double quotes. try the below:

```
" $(dpkg -s cphalo | grep Version | awk '{print $2}') -lt 3.9.5 "
```

or if square braces are needed:

```
" [ $(dpkg -s cphalo | grep Version | awk '{print $2}') -lt 3.9.5 ] "
```

Comment: I have written the condition, but the condition is giving a syntax error from chef recipe.

Comment: the cookbook got uploaded but the chef-client is failing in the node, is there any mistake in my only_if block??

Comment: Have you tried both solutions? `[ y.x -lt a.b ]` will say `0` if `y.x` is smaller than `a.b`.

Comment: failing with another message, maybe? What do you get when you run the shell command on the server?

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about cookbook... `[ 3.9.5 -lt 3.9.5 ]` works with standard shell. At least the **Syntax error**  is fixed.

Comment: `[[` is a shell built-in not a command, and you really don't want to use a string compare for this.